# Collecting logs from hardware devices and application software using syslog-ng

Tags: logging, syslog, rsyslog, syslog-ng

I need to collect logs from devices like Firewall, printers, routers, switches, proxy-servers, mail-servers, db-server, anti-virus software and other softwares for both Linux and Windows platform. Will I be able to do that with any single open-source tools like **syslog-ng**? 
Is there any other similar or different open-source logging tool that can serve my purpose single-handedly?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly it depends on the other devices. If they can send their logs in standard syslog (RFC3164 or RFC5454), then syslog-ng can receive them. Depending on the devices, you can also install syslog-ng as a client and collect logs from files if needed.

For Windows, you will need some other tool that can collect the logs from the windows eventlog and forward it as syslog to your logserver where syslog-ng can receive them. There are both free and commercial tools that can do this (for example, the commercial version of syslog-ng).